Applicability of 1/7 power law for turbulent flow
I am looking to do a CFD study of a turbulent flow through a pipe. I know the average velocity from the flow rate so I decided to use the popular 1/7th power law model for the fully developed turbulent velocity profile. The power law model is:
$$ V = Vmax * pow((1 - abs(z)/zmax), 1.0/n), $$
where n = 7 and $$ Vmax = Vaverage*(1 + 1/n).$$
However, I noticed this model does not give zero gradient when z = 0 or at the center of the axis. Due to symmetry, should we not expect the gradient to be zero at the center?


Welcome. Despite my answer, I believe you may have asked in the wrong place since your question rather seems to address physics than cs.

Denote $\hat{u} = \frac{u}{u_{max}}$, and $\hat{z} = \frac{z}{z_{max}}$ then your power law is given by
$$ \hat{u} = \left(1 - \hat{z}\right)^\frac{1}{n}.$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $\hat{z}$ yields
$$\hat{u}'=\frac{\partial \hat{u}}{\partial{\hat{z}}} = -\frac{1}{n}(1-\hat{z})^{\frac{1-n}{n} }$$
and evaluating the derivative at the center line $\hat{u}'(0) = -1/n$. Hence, based on the model we should not expect a vanishing derivative at the center line and this is considered to be a flaw of the model. See for example here: Velocity Profile Representation for Fully Developed Turbulent Flows in Pipes: A Modified Power Law.

Thanks for sharing the paper. I think the non-zero derivative power law model is more appropriate for flow over a flat plat or similar cases where the flow is not symmetric. Anyway, I will remember your comment for my next post.
